# How to redirect twitter URL's to mobile.twitter.com?

Tags: twitter

I like browsing with Javascript disabled, and Twitter does not work without Javascript. This means all the links people give to regular Twitter URL's break without Javascript installed.

I'd like to redirect these url's to mobile.twitter.com, which works fine without Javascript, but mobile.twitter.com doesn't use the same URL structure (no hashbangs).

Is there a simple tool I can use to redirect twitter.com URL's to mobile.twitter.com?

Comment: This seems very doable with a userscript.

Answer (score 2):

Though not an ideal solution, what I have done before is install a user agent faker/switcher plugin. Then configure to either iOS or Android. So long as the server (website that is visited) has been configured properly it should be redirected to the mobile version of the hyperlink. Unfortunately, far as I've seen, settings are global & lack site specific configuration. So the plugin will have to be disabled or a different browser used. When it is desired to browse in desktop mode.

Two possible candidates;
Chrome: [User-Agent Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg)
Firefox: [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a chrome extension named [Requestly](https://requestly.io/) that works like a charm for redirecting URLs to some other URLs. But incase of twitter, there is a gotcha. Since twitter use service workers to fetch their pages, redirect rule doesn't work for this usecase. So to make it work, we can use the insert script rule instead. You can refer to these answers to know how to make it work:

- [Redirect Twitter Home to Twitter Notifications using Chrome Extension?](https://superuser.com/questions/1630145/redirect-twitter-home-to-twitter-notifications-using-chrome-extension)
- [How to add a parameter to a website (Twitter) using Chrome Extension?](https://superuser.com/questions/1568685/how-to-add-a-parameter-to-a-website-twitter-using-chrome-extension)

There's another way to achieve this use case through Requestly. You can directly use the `user-agent rule` to change the user-agent for twitter to any device (Android, IOS...)

[image]

Here you go. You can directly import this sharedlist directly.
https://app.requestly.io/rules/#sharedList/1615179293900-Twitter-Mobile-User-Agent

Comment: Hi! Your answer seems fine, although it would be preferable to include all the essential information in it rather than just link to other questions. They can get edited or deleted in the future, rendering yours much less useful. Please add relevant information to your answer using the [Edit] button. Quoting and providing a link to original source is fine.