# Redirect Twitter Home to Twitter Notifications using Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, redirection, twitter, requestly

I'm trying to automatically forward all requests to twitter.com/home to twitter.com/notifications . I am trying to use [Requestly Chrome & Firefox extension to set up the redirect](https://requestly.io/) but the following rule is not working.

[image]

Any suggestions or any other way to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter uses [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) to load the home page of twitter which is twitter.com/home. Chrome Extensions do not work well with ServiceWorkers. Hence, the Redirect Rule can not be used to redirect Twitter Pages.

Here is another post - [How to add a parameter to a website (Twitter) using Chrome Extension?](https://superuser.com/questions/1568685/how-to-add-a-parameter-to-a-website-twitter-using-chrome-extension) which explains how we can change the URL for websites (e.g. Twitter) which uses ServiceWorkers.

We can use [Requestly Insert Script Feature](https://medium.com/requestly-docs/inserting-scripts-dynamically-in-a-webpage-be4af90da20a) to insert scripts on the web pages which works fine.

In this example, there's a simple script which runs on twitter.com/home and redirects to twitter.com/notifications

You can write your own custom code in the code block if you want redirect to be performed in a certain way or based on some other conditions.

[image: Redirect Twitter Home to Twitter Notifications using Requestly Script feature]

Here's a SharedList https://app.requestly.io/rules/#sharedList/1614680032887-Twitter-Home-to-Notifications which you can [directly import](https://docs.requestly.io/managing-rules/sharing#import-a-shared-list) and you will get the rule in a single click.

#### References

- https://medium.com/requestly-docs/inserting-scripts-dynamically-in-a-webpage-be4af90da20a
- https://docs.requestly.io/managing-rules/sharing#import-a-shared-list